# Echo modified time of file

Tags: php, date, datetime, joomla3.0

I am trying to get the modified time of my css file. I have tried the following:

```
$filename = '/~site/templates/mytemplate/css/template.css';
$filename2 = "/~site/templates/mytemplate/test.html";

echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename)) ."<br>";
echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", getlastmod($filename)) ."<br>"

echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename2)) ."<br>";
echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", getlastmod($filename2)) ."<br>";
```

**Returns**

Last modified: December 31 1969 18:00:00.

Last modified: November 06 2013 09:18:52.

Last modified: December 31 1969 18:00:00.

Last modified: November 06 2013 09:18:52.

But the actual mod date was yesterday, so it should be November 18 2013 16:01:00
The second file was this morning and I just created it to test!

What am I doing wrong? Is it the server returning the wrong date?

Comment: `getlastmod()` doesn't accept any arguments, as it returns the last modified time of the current file.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, and echo `filemtime($filename1)` only (without wrapping it with `date()`). I suspect the file may not be accessible (read permissions), or doesn't exist, and so returns `0`. Then due to timezone difference `date()` returns unix epoch (1 january 1970) for value `0`, minus 6 hours, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filemtime()` returns `FALSE` on failure. That's why you're receiving *Last modified: December 31 1969 18:00:00* on output. `FALSE` evaluates to `0` so:

```
date("F d Y H:i:s.", 0) == 'January 01 1970 00:00:00'
```

(minus 6 hours due to your timezone, I guess).
The reason that `filemtime()` returns `FALSE` is probably the `$filename` doesn't exist. You should check it first:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename)) ."<br>";
}
```

The problem with `getlastmod()` is obvious. As we can read in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/getlastmod), this function

> *Gets the time of the last modification of **the main script** of execution*

**EDIT**:
According to the discussion in the comments below this answer - the solution was to cut down the path to the file to:

```
$filename = 'css/template.css';
```

Comment: I am fine with the timezone being off if I can get this to work. It still returns false even though I know the file is there. I can go to it via the browser and obviously its my css file so the site is showing the correct styles. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @ChadJTreadway if the file works on client-side it doesn't mean it will work on server-side. Try to _var\_dump_ these functions: `file_exists($filename)` or `getcwd()` and tell me what you got.

Comment: @ChadJTreadway so you're already inside the `templates/cubecreative/`. Your `$filename` variable should be cut down to `css/template.css`.

Comment: that worked! I am so used to having to drill down for Joomla that I forget how to do the simple things! Posted the joomla solution below your solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at the notes in the bottom of the following link :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Or can you try with `stat()`function ?

```
$stat = stat('path/to/file');
echo 'Modification time: ' . $stat['mtime'];
```

Comment: This too returns false much like the above.